# Markdown image not shown

Tags: html, markdown

I am writing some markdown ducuments using `markdown pro` (http://www.markdownpro.com/)

somehow not all images i add are shown in the final document:

i add them like this

```
<img src="./img/clv.png" height="100"/>
```

but the result looks like that

[image]

the file structure looks like that:

[image]

whereas 'summary' is my .md file

i have also tried markdown syntax

```
![](./img/clv.png)
```

and explicit closing tags

```
<img></img>
```

but always get the same result, no image is shown.

other ways i tried:

```
<img src="./img/clv.png" height="100"/>
<img src="../img/clv.png" height="100"/>
<img src="img/clv.png" height="100"/>
<img src="~/img/clv.png" height="100"/>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot, there is no extension to the `summary` file. I think it should be `summary.md`. Additionally, we can see extensions to the image files. So extensions are definitely enabled. This might mean that `summary` is not a markdown file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, try using the following tags instead:

```
<img src="../img/clv.png" height="100"/>
<img src="img/clv.png" height="100"/>
<img src="~/img/clv.png" height="100"/>
```

It looks like as if the problem is associated with the image's relative path. If this is correct, one of the above tags will work.